# Angular2 - how to observe an Array?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

This is what I have:

**//settings.ts**

```
public messages : Array<Message>;

public static getInstance() {
   if (this.instance == null) {
      this.instance = new Settings();
   }
      return this.instance;
}

this.client.onMessageArrived = (message: Message) => {
  this.messages.push(message);     //new message is pushed in to the array
};
```

**//log.component.ts**

```
public msgs: Array<String>;

Settings.getInstance().messages.forEach(element => {
   this.msgs.push(element.getText());  //here I get the messages from settings.ts
});
```

**//log.component.html**

```
<ng-container  *ngFor="let msg of msgs">
   <md-card>{{msg}}</md-card>
</ng-container>
```

So what I want is: every time when a new Messege arrives, the html should show the new message too.

I know that I have to use Observables and I did look for help on the internet, but I still dont know how to solve this....

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Following code helps you,

```
 Settings.getInstance()
        .subscribe((messages)= >{
          messages.forEach(element => {
                this.msgs.push(element.getText());  //here I get the messages from settings.ts
                });
        });
```

The service should be modified as

```
    public static getInstance() :Obserable<Message[]>) {
        if (this.instance == null) {
            //your http service call and map the response object 
        }
        return this.instance;
    }
.
.
.
this.client.onMessageArrived = (message: Message) => {
            this.messages.push(message);     //new message is pushed in to the array
        };
.
.
```

Comment: i tried but i dont know how to do : //your http service call and map the response object

Comment: is there any way just to observe "public messages : Array<Message>;"

Comment: Follow this [**steps**](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html)

Comment: @ALSTRA is the above solution worked or you need more help?

Comment: i solved the problem on a different way, but I would like to know how to do it with observebles too, so if you have time to explain it please do it :)